# RFID Emulator Software

Tags: software, rfid, emulator

I do not know if it exists but what I want to achieve is relatively easy:

I want a software for RFID emulation just to analyse the execution time of the program that I wrote. The emulator does not need to be something complex, I just want to find that if this program gets to be executed on a real RFID reader, approximately how much time will it take to complete its execution?

Does such an emulator exist for RFID? With a little research I found Rifidi but I am not sure it has the functionality for such kind of timing analysis.

Comment: Apologies for the obvious questions.  Can you use an actual RFID tag?  Do you expect that the execution of your program will vary significantly from one tag to another?

Comment: you need to be more specific and provide leads.  How many RFID chips are there available? there is no generic answer to such a broad question.  What vendor are you looking at?, what is the part number?  Chances are the vendor used an existing uC to implement the part so the op-codes are similar.

Comment: From what i understand, you want to emulate the reader itself and thus also the timing behavior between the reader and the RFID tag. Since every reader may have its own firmware implementation and different RFID tag types behave totally different in regard to timing, there is no general way to emulate this. You are probably targeting a specific reader for use with one or more specific tag types, so my advise would be to get the actual hardware.

Comment: OK I need this analysis for a school project and we do not want to get into hardware unless it is really required. The timings does not need to be accurate to milliseconds level, I did not implement it for a specific reader, this is only a simulation of a security protocol for RFID written in Java. Therefore it will not work in real hardware I assume.

Comment: Since it is some kind of a simulation, we also want to find the timings to ensure that if it were implemented for a real RFID reader and tested on a real device, this protocol will not run too slow to affect the communication process.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use Rifidi for timing analysis, you can only use it to see if your protocol implementation is correct and your software acts and reacts like intended. The commands sent to Rifidi are a huge factor slower then when using a real RFID reader.